# AngularJS, Input and selects no action on mobile

Tags: html, angularjs

I have a problem when I try to test the front-end in mobile version.

The Selects and inputs don´t get focus and don't allow data insertion.

Are there any known issues with angularjs that might be causing this?

Comment: Sounds like a styling/CSS issue not an AngularJS one.

Comment: @Carson 
There is no CSS interference here. I checked now.